# Can't compile with Facebook Android SDK and Facebook Audience Network SDK

Tags: android, react-native, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-audience-network

I have a react-native app and I'm trying to import the FB Android SDK and FB Audience Network SDK with the mediation adapter.

When I add these dependencies in my app/build.gradle, I get the following errors during build.

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1' 
compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.26.1'
compile 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:4.26.1.0'
```

Errors:

```
C:\ig3\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v24\values-v24.xml:3: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

C:\ig3\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v24\values-v24.xml:4: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.

C:\ig3\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v24\values-v24.xml:3: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

C:\ig3\android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v24\values-v24.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
```

The only way I could get my project to compile was to do this in android/build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    ....
    configurations.all {
       resolutionStrategy {
         eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
           if (details.requested.group == 'com.facebook.react' && details.requested.name == 'react-native') {
             details.useVersion "0.49.5" // Your real React Native version here
           }
         }
         force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1' <---Add this line
         force 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.26.1' <---Add this line
       }
    }
}
```

And comment out these two lines in android/app/build.gradle:

```
//compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1' 
//compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.26.1'
compile 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:4.26.1.0'
```

If I try any other version of FB Android SDK in android/build.gradle I get the same errors mentioned earlier. After some research, I tried changing the com.android.support:appcompat version but it will always give the same error as above if I do not use 23.

Is this an acceptable way to include these dependencies? It feels like a hack, I don't know why I could not just include the sdks in android/app/build.gradle, and I don't want to be stuck on FB android sdk version 4.22.1 forever.

Also, after testing it does not seem like ad mediation is working from Admob for Facebook Audience Network but I am unsure if it is due to the way I import the sdk like above or an unrelated issue.

If anybody can show me how to correctly include the sdks I would appreciate it. Thanks!

EDIT:
Full android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
       resolutionStrategy {
         eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
           if (details.requested.group == 'com.facebook.react' && details.requested.name == 'react-native') {
             details.useVersion "0.49.5" // Your real React Native version here
           }
         }
         force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1'
         force 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.26.1'
       }
    }
}
```

And full android/app/build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 50
        versionName "1.11.11"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            ....
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23+'

    compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile project(':react-native-billing')
    compile project(':bugsnag-react-native')
    compile project(':react-native-admob')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])

    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(':react-native-code-push')
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    compile project(':react-native-config')
    compile project(':react-native-fast-image')
    compile project(':react-native-camera')
    compile project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')

    compile(project(":react-native-google-signin")) {
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms" // very important
    }

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.6.0'

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1' 
    compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.26.1'
    compile 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:4.26.1.0'

}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

Comment: I know this is maybe not at all what you are looking for but I had a issue today using `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'` and `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1'`, check if removing play-services-auth does anything.

Comment: @H.Brooks removing play-services-auth doesn't have any effect. If I remove `compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.26.1'` then my app builds (from full android/app/build.gradle above). However this is something I need. Any ideas?

Comment: Let me check then I will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to update all these:

```
gradle to 3.01
gradle wrapper to 4.1
compilesdkversion to 26
buildtoolsversion to 26.02
com.android.support:appcompat-v7 to 26+
com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0
```

and my app builds successfully